# How to get my external and internal drives to show up on the desktop

Tags: macos, hard-drive, catalina

I have a 2020 iMac running Catalina. I would like for my internal drive and my external drives to show up on my desktop. Currently I have a blank desktop. I have tried going to Finder/Preferences and selecting the General tab. From General I check the boxes for Hard Disks and Internal Disk but they don't show up. Is there a command line tool to display them?

When I first started my new computer the internal drive and the external drives all showed up on my desktop. Later that day I used migration assistant to transfer the files i wanted to to my new machine. Since then none of my drives show up on the desktop.

Comment: If the Finder pref doesn't work, why would a command line? They should appear top right, under the date & spotlight menu items. The pref switch in Finder is instantaneous [with a small fade in/out].

Comment: i didn't know if there was another command other than using the command line. When i  tried the Finder/Preferences method it didn't work.

Comment: When i first started up my mac all my mounted Volumes appeared on the desk top.  Later that day I used migration assistant. Since then all the drives have vanished from the desktop.

Comment: You ought to include that information in your question - random weirdness after Migration Assistant doesn't surprise me at all these days. I've lost all faith in it. I'd very carefully check what else is wrong - or better still, use a clone of your old drive rather than trust Time Machine.

Comment: @user3439894.  That worked!!  If you want to post that as an answer i'll accept it!  Thanks very much...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In **Terminal**, run the following *compound command*:

```
defaults delete com.apple.finder; killall -HUP Finder
```

Then go to **Finder** > **Preferences…** > **General** and under **Show these items on the desktop**, check **Hard disks** and check **External disks**.